# UNIX multiple if conditions

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have some problem with my code here. This is my code:

```
#!bin/sh
grep "$1" Rail.txt > test.txt
if [ "$#" -eq 1 -a grep -q "$1" test.txt ]; then 
    grep "$1" Rail.txt
else
    echo not found
fi
```

Problem:

It says: `script.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments` every time I run it.
I'm not sure what's wrong with my condition whether I use the wrong operators or parenthesis or square brackets.

Comment: How big is the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a semi-educated guess, what you want to write is:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && grep -q "$1" test.txt; then
```

---

> On what ocassions should we use the square brackets?

Historically, the test command, `/bin/test` was linked to `/bin/[`, and was an external command, not a shell built-in.  These days (and for several decades now), it has been a shell built-in.  However, it follows the structure of a command, requiring spaces to separate arguments, and if it is invoked as `[`, then the last argument must be `]`.

As to when you use it, you use it when you need to test a condition.

Note that you can write:

```
if ls; false; true; then echo "the last command counts"; else echo "no it doesn't"; fi
```

The `if` command executes a sequence of one or more commands, and tests the exit status of the last command.  If the exit status is 0, success, the `then` clause is executed; if the exit status is not 0, then the `else` clause is taken.

So, you can use the test when you need to test something.  It can be part of an `if` or `elif` or `while` (or `until`).  It can also be used on its own with `||` or `&&`:

```
[ -z "$1" ] && echo "No arguments - or the first argument is an empty string"

[ "$var1" -gt "$var2" ] || echo "Oops!" && exit 1
```

These could be written as `if` statements too, of course:

```
if  [ -z "$1" ]
then echo "No arguments - or the first argument is an empty string"
fi

if [ "$var1" -le "$var2" ]
then
    echo "Oops!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Note that I needed to invert the test in the second rewrite.  Bash has a built-in `!` operator which inverts the exit status of the command that follows, so I could also have written:

```
if ! [ "$var1" -gt "$var2" ]
```

and `test` has a `!` too, so it could also be written:

```
if [ ! "$var1" -gt "$var2" ]
```

Comment: Rather too literally 'years of experience'.

Comment: in what ocassions should we use the square brackets ?